# JavaScript Event Not Firing

Tags: javascript, events

So I recently decided to start learning JavaScript. I come from only knowing VB.NET for programming knowledge and HTML & CSS for design. Anyway, scrap.tf is a website for TF2 banking which makes things automatic. I am planning to write a basic Chrome plugin, and I want to be able to if the button is clicked, this function will happen. I've got this all set up but when the button's clicked, it only takes me to scrap.tf/hats, EnQueueHatBank(); is the JS command they use there to join the queue. This even never fires unless I type it in after I'm on the site. Do I need to wait for it to fire?

```
if (location.href === 'http://scrap.tf/hats')
{
    EnQueueHatBank();
}
else
{
    window.location.href='http://scrap.tf/hats';
    EnQueueHatBank();
}
```

Comment: `=` is an assignment `==` is a comparison.

Comment: Try `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this talk of `=` vs `==` is missing the point. You're changing `window.location` *before* you call `EnQueueHatBank`, so you navigate to a new page before the function is ever called. That's what's stopping it from running. So the first thing you need to do is:

1. Call EnQueueHatBank first.

   ```
   if (location.href === 'http://www.scrap.tf/hats') {
       EnQueueHatBank();
   } else {
       EnQueueHatBank();
       window.location.href='http://www.scrap.tf/hats';
   }
   ```
2. Clean up the code a little, because the structure is a little awkward. You're calling `EnQueueHatBank` either way, so there's no need for it to be in the if statement:

   ```
   EnQueueHatBank();

   if (window.location.href !== 'http://www.scrap.tf/hats') {
       window.location.href = 'http://www.scrap.tf/hats';
   }
   ```
3. Finally, remember that `http://www.scrap.tf/hats/` probably goes to the same place as `http://www.scrap.tf/hats`, not to mention `https://www.scrap.tf/hats?foo=bar` and so forth.  You'd be better off with a less-strict test:

   ```
   EnQueueHatBank();

   if (window.location.href.indexOf('://www.scrap.tf/hats') > -1) {
       window.location.href = 'http://www.scrap.tf/hats';
   }
   ```

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, you will need to do this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('://www.scrap.tf/hats') > -1) {
    EnQueueHatBank();
} 
else {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.scrap.tf/hats';
}
```

This will only work if your program runs again after navigating to `scrap.tf/hats`, so make sure it runs every time you load a new page.

For security reasons, you cannot initiate code on one page and have it continue after you've navigated somewhere else. You'll have to call `EnQueueHatBank` from the page it's meant to run on.

Comment: Well, the thing is. It should be on that page before the command is used because if not, EnQueueHatBank() means nothing.

Comment: @TylerDunn In that case, try his second solution with the function below the conditional check and see if the results differ.

Comment: They don't. It needs to be on scrap.tf/hats BEFORE EnQueueHatBank() is fired.

Comment: Fixed my issue of it not redirecting, my issue now is once it redirects, EnQueueHatBank() isn't fired.

Comment: Is there a way to have EnQueueHatBank as a separate function then, and have on the else it do that function or is that still considered continuing the code?

Comment: @TylerDunn - I'm not sure I understand your question. But your program has to run again from the beginning every time you load a new page. Once it hits `window.location.href='http://www.scrap.tf/hats'`, it stops what it's doing and navigates. In my last example, if you start on `google.com`, it will navigate to `scrap.tf/hats`, start over, figure out it's in the right place, and run `EnQueueHatBank`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to correct the comparison to use two equal signs.

```
if (location.href == 'http://www.scrap.tf/hats')
{
    EnQueueHatBank();
}
```

Once you end up with tools like jslint, javascript even offers a `===` operator, which does type checking, too (checks if both sides are strings, as in this example).

Answer (score 1):

You should use comparison `===` operation, but you did an value assignment `=`.

```
if (location.href === 'http://www.scrap.tf/hats')
{
    EnQueueHatBank();
}
else
{
    window.location.href='http://www.scrap.tf/hats';
    EnQueueHatBank();
}
```

Comment: It still redirects me to the page even if I'm on it. :(

Comment: you're having same function in both if and else part.  are you getting  any errors?

Comment: @TylerDunn Great! possible to share the fix?

Comment: Removed www. from it and it wouldn't redirect anymore. My issue now is if it isn't on the page, after it redirects, EnQueueHatBank() isn't fired.

Comment: @TylerDunn better make like this `if (window.location.href !== 'http://www.scrap.tf/hats')
{
    window.location.href = 'http://www.scrap.tf/hats';
}  EnQueueHatBank();`

Comment: Still not getting fired. :/

Comment: @TylerDunn show your `EnQueueHatBank()` code.  I think there may be the problem

Comment: put `console.log()` to debug values.  open developer tools F12 to get error.